# How to enable ssl in reactive mongodb client in spring boot?

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, reactive-streams

I am currently running into an issue while creating a reactive mongoclient when I provide the URL with ssl=true option.
I am creating configuration class in spring boot where I create Reactive mongoclient using the following option:
MongoClients.create(Connections ring Conn)
Here when I try to connect to a DB with no ssl settings it works, but with ssl enabled option I am getting error saying NettyEventLoop class is not found.
Can anyone suggest what I can do to fix this issue

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that the API has changed, so since MongoDB driver v3.8, the method is "applyToSslSettings":

```
import com.mongodb.Block;
import com.mongodb.connection.SslSettings;
import com.mongodb.connection.SslSettings.Builder;
import com.mongodb.connection.netty.NettyStreamFactoryFactory;

import io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoopGroup;

@Configuration
public class Config {

    private NioEventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

    @Bean
    public MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer sslCustomizer() {

        Block<SslSettings.Builder> sslSettingsBlock = new Block<SslSettings.Builder>() {
            @Override
            public void apply(Builder t) {
                t.applySettings(SslSettings.builder()
                .enabled(true)
                .invalidHostNameAllowed(true)
                .build());
            }
        };

        return clientSettingsBuilder -> clientSettingsBuilder
                .applyToSslSettings(sslSettingsBlock)
                .streamFactoryFactory(NettyStreamFactoryFactory.builder()
                        .eventLoopGroup(eventLoopGroup).build());
    }

    @PreDestroy
    public void shutDownEventLoopGroup() {
        eventLoopGroup.shutdownGracefully();
    }
}
```

Comment: This works; I just needed to add `.context(mongoDbSslContext)` to `SslSettings.Builder`.

Answer (score -1):

I was able to overcome this issue by configuring MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer and NioEventLoop Group.
Please find below the code:

```
private NioEventLoopGroup eventLoopGroup = new NioEventLoopGroup();

 @Bean
           public MongoClientSettingsBuilderCustomizer sslCustomizer() {
                return clientSettingsBuilder -> clientSettingsBuilder
                        .sslSettings(SslSettings.builder()
                                .enabled(true)
                                .invalidHostNameAllowed(true)
                                .build())
                        .streamFactoryFactory(NettyStreamFactoryFactory.builder()
                                .eventLoopGroup(eventLoopGroup).build());
            }
```